# Building a call to a SoapClient in PHP

Tags: php, soap

I am new to SOAP and trying to figure out how to build a call to a SOAP server.  Here is the definition of what I am trying to get:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:prov="http://bridgewatersystems.com/xpc/subscribermetering/service/provisioning/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <prov:GetMeteringStateRequest>
              <subscriber subscriber-id="USERID" />
          </prov:GetMeteringStateRequest>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here is the PHP I am using to test (and not working of course):

```
$user_id = "REALIDHERE";

$parameters->subscriber_id = $user_id;
$parameters->MIN = "test";
$parameters->partition_key = "test";

try {
  $client = new SoapClient("http://SOAPIP:32010/soap/services/SubscriberMeteringProvisionAPI.wsdl");

  echo "trying...\n";
  print( $client->GetMeteringState( new SoapParam("subscriber", $parameters ) ) );
} catch (SoapFault $e) {
  //var_dump($e);
}
```

Any help on getting the call to GetMeteringState() to work would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: What error do you see? what happens/does not happen?

Comment: $parameters->subscriber->subscriber_id = $user_id;
print( $client->GetMeteringState( $parameters ) );

If I end up using that, I get:

["faultstring"]=>
  string(9) "Not Found"
  ["faultcode"]=>
  string(4) "HTTP"

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend checking out the XML that is generated by your request. This is explained pretty well [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastrequest.php), but here's an example:

```
// prepare SoapClient
$client = new SoapClient("http://.../SubscriberMeteringProvisionAPI.wsdl");
print( $client->GetMeteringState( new SoapParam("subscriber", $parameters ) ) );

// output the XML request
echo "<pre>".$client->__getLastRequest()."</pre>";
```

Comment: Unfortunately it never gets to the call for __getLastRequest() since GetMeteringState() is throwing an Exception as noted above.

Comment: In that case I would check to see if the server has a firewall in place which might be blocking the connection.

Comment: It isn't, I am getting reponses from the server.  I ended up just posted the formatted XML request to the SOAP server via cURL and calling ita  day.